# Calling insert stored procedure using entity framework that has return parameter

Tags: asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-6

I am writing a logic for inserting record using Entity Framework store procedure that will return an int parameter that is TeamId. I have created the function import for the store procedure. Please see the screenshot below

[image]

I am not sure how to return the int parameter. Please see the code below

**DataAccess layer**

```
public int InsertTeam(string countryCode, string teamName, string TeamDescription, string createdBy, char isActive)
        {
            using (var mcrContext = new MCREntities())
            {
                return (from team in mcrContext.InsertTeam(countryCode, teamName, TeamDescription, createdBy, true)


                        select 
                        {


                        }).ToList();
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

What you get back from the procedure is an `ObjectResult<T>`. In your situation simply do:

```
public int InsertTeam(string countryCode, string teamName, string TeamDescription, string createdBy, char isActive)
{
    using (var mcrContext = new MCREntities())
    {
        var result = mcrContext.InsertTeam(countryCode, teamName, TeamDescription, createdBy, true);
        return result.Single().Value;
    }
}
```